# The effect of base change on the L-function of GL(2)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Let $F$ be a local field (whose residue field is $q$) and $E$ its quadratic extension. Let $\pi$ be a irreducible principal series representation $\pi(\chi_1, \chi_2)$ of $GL_F(2)$ especially where $\chi_1, \chi_2$ are unitary characters. Then I know $L_F(s,\pi)=\frac{1}{1-\chi_1(\varpi)q^s} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\chi_2(\varpi)q^s}$. Then what is $L_E(s,BC(\pi))$ in terms of $\chi_1, \chi_2$?

Comment: Is $E$ meant to be the unique unramified extension (in char not $2$?

Comment: @Garrett, you are right!, E is unramified extension. I missed it.

Comment: Do you mean to assume that $\chi_i$ are unramified characters?

Comment: @David, you are right. $\chi_i$ are unramified characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\pi = \pi(\chi_1, \chi_2)$ is an irreducible principal series, then $BC(\pi)$ is the irreducible principal series attached to the unramified characters $\chi_i \circ N_{E/F}$ of $E^\times$. So if the $\chi_i$ are unramified then we have

$$L_E(s, BC(\pi)) =  (1 - \chi_1(\varpi)^2 q^{-2s})^{-1}(1 - \chi_2(\varpi)^2 q^{-2s})^{-1}.$$

(The point of base change is that it corresponds to restriction of Weil-Deligne representations from $W_F$ to $W_E$ under the local Langlands correspondence, and this relation is completely obvious on the Galois side, since the Frobenius of $E$ is the square of the Frobenius of $F$.)